# Laravel (How do I add data to database)

Tags: php, laravel

Here's my code that shows projects assigned to a user.

HomeController

```
public function index()
{
    $companies = auth()->user()->companies;
    $projects  = Project::whereIn('company_id',$companies->pluck('id'))->get();

    return view('home',compact('companies','projects'));
}
```

home.blade.php

```
@forelse($projects as $project)
    <a href="{{ route('issues.show', $project->id) }}" class="text-xl font-bold m-5 text-white">{{$project->title}}</a>
                
@empty
    <p>No Projects</p>
@endforelse
```

ProjectController that show issues within the project.

```
public function show($id){
      $project = Project::findOrFail($id);

    $issues = $project->issues;
    return view('issues', compact('issues', 'project'));
}
```

route:

```
Route::get('/issues/{id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::class, 'show'])->name('issues.show');
```

issues.blade.php

```
@forelse($issues as $issue)
    <a href="" class="text-xl font-bold m-5 text-white">{{$issue->title}}</a>
@empty
    <p>No Issues</p>
@endforelse
```

I made a button in the issues page that shows a modal that has a form for adding issues for the selected project. Can you help me with this? On how to do that?

Comment: So, you would like to create popup with form, which add new `issue` which gonna be assigned to project?

Comment: @AdrianZavis Yes.

Comment: Well, you have list of all projects and there is one popup. Am I correct?

Comment: @Gab Romero You need the view/frontend logic or the backendlogic?

Comment: @AdrianZavis Yes. I edited my question and included the code for the blades.

Comment: @AdrianZavis The backend logic.

Comment: I don't know your database schema. So I cannot tell you how to save it. I provided you way to get project id into backend.

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question? Which part are you struggling with? Showing the modal? Showing all needed fields in the modal? Sending the form fields to the server? Persisting that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's imagine you have project controller like this.

```
public function show($id){
    $project = Project::findOrFail($id);

    return view('issues', compact('project'));
}
```

You don' have to pass issues into blade. You can print it easily there.

**Your blade**

```
<table>
@foreach($project->issues as $issue)
   <tr>
      <td>{{ $issue->name }}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

**Your form in your popup in blade**

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
   <input name="project_id" type="hidden" value="{{ $project->id }}"/>
   <!-- all inputs you need -->
</form>
```

So what we did. You pasted the project id into form in hidden input. So now, after form submit you have in your backend input called `project_id` in your request.

**In your issue controller**

```
public function show(Request $request){
    dd($request->project_id); //there is your project_id 
}
```

Probably you have column `project_id` in your issues. So you can save it with `$issue->associate($project_id)`. That's just an example!!

I don't know other fields you need to save with your issue, so I cannot help you more. I think you have got everything you needed to make a draft. :)

GL